# How to add other themes for Jekyll Now?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am using Jekyll Now on GitHub Pages.

`Version 1.2.0`

My question is how do I add other themes that are compatible with `Jekyll Now`?

Is it simply a case of adding the `theme: <themename>` into the `_config.yml`?

This is the [list of themes](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now#other-forkable-themes) compatible with `Jekyll Now`

Comment: Have you tried doing what you suggested in the question (adding theme: <themename> into _config.yml)? If so, were you successful?

Comment: Yes i tried. No it was not successful

Answer (score 3):

Jekyll Now is a theme itself for Jekyll.

You linked a set of themes 'compatible' with Jekyll now. However, that is not the case, the author states that you can use the Workflow with those other themes (i.e. fork a new repository, change the _config.yml, etc).

If you want to change the theme of Jekyll Now you would have to basically alter the whole folder structure such that you would be basically using one of those other repos.